# Lyric interpretation of the song "Tuesday" by Drake and iLoveMakonnen

Tags: lyrics, meaning

In the song "Tuesday" by Drake and iLoveMakonnen, there is a repeated lyric:

> Got your girl in the cut and she choosey

What is the meaning of this line? Specifically, what does it mean to have a girl in the cut, and what is the implication of her being choosey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"In the cut" means something that's secret or hidden. "Choosey" means someone who is particular about what they like. In this case, the singer is secretly flirting with someone else's girl at a club, even though she's so particular that she wouldn't normally look at other men.

This interpretation has actually been confirmed by the songwriter:

> “In the cut” is when someone’s in the club—with who they came with, but at the same time sneaky, looking at you. Not all out in the open. In the cut.
> https://genius.com/8043320